# how to use call a handler in an activity from another activity or main class

Tags: java, android, inputstream, handler, outputstream

I am trying to communicate with USB on android using input-output stream, for that I am using handler in an activity, it was working fine but if use handler in every activity separately it is not working properly so I wish to make a common activity and communicate within the activity as a mediator of all activity, I tried something like

```
public class BasicAccessoryDemo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button mycontrol, close_command;
        mycontrol = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_command);
        mycontrol.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.send_command:
                byte[] commandPacket = new byte[2];
                commandPacket[0] =0x12;
                commandPacket[1] =0x34;
                Usb_Communciation.Send_message(commandPacket);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

and the another class which holds handler was

```
public class Usb_Communciation extends Activity{
    public final static int USBAccessoryWhat = 0;
    public int firmwareProtocol = 0;
    public static USBAccessoryManager accessoryManager;
    public static String TAG = "MICROCHIP";
    public static final int APP_CONNECT                 = (int)0xAE;
    public boolean deviceAttached = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        accessoryManager = new USBAccessoryManager(handler, USBAccessoryWhat);
       //accessoryManager.enable(this, getIntent());
    }

    public static void Send_message(byte[] data) {
        try{
            accessoryManager.write(data);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "USBAccessoryManager:write():IOException: arasu "
                            + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            byte[] commandPacket = new byte[64];
            byte[] WriteValue = new byte[2];

            switch(msg.what)
            {
                case USBAccessoryWhat:
                    boolean StopReading = true;
                    int count = 0;
                    switch(((USBAccessoryManagerMessage)msg.obj).type)
                    {
                        case READ:
                            if(accessoryManager.isConnected() == false) {
                                return;
                            }
                            while(true) {
                                if (accessoryManager.available() < 2) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case READY:
                            String version = ((USBAccessoryManagerMessage)msg.obj).accessory.getVersion();
                            firmwareProtocol = getFirmwareProtocol(version);
                            switch(firmwareProtocol){
                                case 1:
                                    deviceAttached = true;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    deviceAttached = true;
                                    commandPacket[0] = (byte) APP_CONNECT;
                                    commandPacket[1] = 0;
                                    accessoryManager.write(commandPacket);                                  
                                    Log.d(TAG,"connect message sent.");
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }   //switch
        } //handleMessage
    }; //handler

    public int getFirmwareProtocol(String version) {
        String major = "0";
        int positionOfDot;
        positionOfDot = version.indexOf('.');
        if(positionOfDot != -1) {
            major = version.substring(0, positionOfDot);
        }
        return new Integer(major).intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should make this a singleton. Is there a reason why it's an Activity?

Comment: no reason i just tried it as a activity, simply to add oncreate

Comment: Yep, then I'd use a Singleton pattern. Put all your logic in there and you can access it from everywhere. Here's an [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_singleton.htm) of how to create one in Java

Comment: thanks, i would try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an activity class like a normal java class, I have seen that the second activity hasn't any view file. You can create a normal class called UsbCommunication with a constructor and initialize it in your activity like this:

```
public class Usb_Communciation {
    public final static int USBAccessoryWhat = 0;
    public int firmwareProtocol = 0;
    public static USBAccessoryManager accessoryManager;
    public static String TAG = "MICROCHIP";
    public static final int APP_CONNECT                 = (int)0xAE;
    public boolean deviceAttached = false;


    public Usb_Communciation (/*Pass neccesary parameters here from activity*/) {
       accessoryManager = new USBAccessoryManager(handler, USBAccessoryWhat);
    }


    public void Send_message(byte[] data) {
       try{
           accessoryManager.write(data);
       }catch (Exception e){
          Log.d(TAG,
                "USBAccessoryManager:write():IOException: arasu "
                        + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public Handler handler = new Handler() {
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           byte[] commandPacket = new byte[64];
           byte[] WriteValue = new byte[2];

           switch(msg.what)
           {
            case USBAccessoryWhat:
                boolean StopReading = true;
                int count = 0;
                switch(((USBAccessoryManagerMessage)msg.obj).type)
                {
                    case READ:
                        if(accessoryManager.isConnected() == false) {
                            return;
                        }
                        while(true) {
                            if (accessoryManager.available() < 2) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case READY:
                        String version = ((USBAccessoryManagerMessage)msg.obj).accessory.getVersion();
                        firmwareProtocol = getFirmwareProtocol(version);
                        switch(firmwareProtocol){
                            case 1:
                                deviceAttached = true;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                deviceAttached = true;
                                commandPacket[0] = (byte) APP_CONNECT;
                                commandPacket[1] = 0;
                                accessoryManager.write(commandPacket);                                  
                                Log.d(TAG,"connect message sent.");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }   //switch
    } //handleMessage
}; //handler

   public int getFirmwareProtocol(String version) {
       String major = "0";
       int positionOfDot;
       positionOfDot = version.indexOf('.');
       if(positionOfDot != -1) {
        major = version.substring(0, positionOfDot);
    }
    return new Integer(major).intValue();
}
```

And in your activity call the function:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.send_command:
            byte[] commandPacket = new byte[2];
            commandPacket[0] =0x12;
            commandPacket[1] =0x34;
            Usb_Communication usbCom = new Usb_Communication();
            usbCom.Send_message(commandPacket);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to get the data from hander in activity without using on click whenever any new data come through the Usb_Communication handler in the class. In other way, I want to receive the data from Usb_communication whenever handler gets new msg. Right now it receives when on click event happens.

Answer (score 1):

In this case we use [IntentService](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183). Where you define an IntentService which is a class that will work in background when an action is received. Then you can process your input-output stream (in background!! which is what we want) and then send a broadcast to your activities using [BroadcastReceiver](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Handler in your Application class.

```
public class YourApp extends Application {

    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Then you can get a handler from other components, for example from Activity:

```
((YourApp)getApplication()).getHandler();
```

Don't forget to set the application name in the Manifest file.

```
<application
    android:name=".YourApp"
....>
```